# How to remove spaces between parentheses in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Given the string:

```
val s = "[ a + 5 + (   1   +  2)]"
```

I need to convert it to:

```
[ a + 5 + (1+2)]
```

How should I achieve this? Regex?

Spaces should be removed from within parentheses: any other spaces in the string should remain as-is.

Another example:

```
aaa   bbb   ccc   (   1   +   2   )
```

should return:

```
aaa   bbb   ccc   (1+2)
```

Another example:

```
(  1  +  2  )  +  (  3  +  4  )
```

should return:

```
(1+2)  +  (3+4)
```

Comment: Oh god... Since parens can be nested, the answer is no. No matter how hard you try, you cannot write such a regex.

Comment: This question is incomplete without showing the full range of possible test cases that the regex would need to deal with.

Comment: What about `([   1 + 2  ] +    3)` would that remove all spaces? Does the behavior change when things are nested? *Can* they be nested?

Comment: `Any` space in the parenthesis should be removed, the result of your example would be `([1+2]+3)`

Comment: @Alec Ever heard of a recursive regex? It's very well possible, it just depends on the regex engine.

Comment: added another example

Comment: @4castle: Scala uses Java regex, so it is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible for the parentheses to be arbitrarily nested? Like `( 1 + 2 + ( 1 + 3 ))`? If so, you will need to load a regex library that allows for recursive regexes, like PCRE, or parse with a `Stack`.

Comment: @4castle No. That is not regex. That is not to say that there do not exist extensions, but the point is OP should not be looking down that avenue. Furthermore, I don't think Scala regex has such extensions either.

Comment: @Alec Here's a PCRE regex that can handle it: `\((?:[^()]*(?R)?)+?\)` [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL7xR7/4)

Comment: Would you please say how with this regex will you be able to catch spaces? @4castle

Comment: @revo You would remove spaces from the matches to that regex.

Comment: Ok so you mean it's not a job for a single regex to catch those spaces even with recursions available. @4castle

Comment: @4castle PCRE is, despite its name, _not_ a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `?R` is part of an extension. I am fully aware these things exist (and have played a lot with them) - but they are at best extensions. And, as I mentioned, Scala regex doesn't have this.

Comment: @Alec See [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages) of that article. I never claimed to be using a regular expression.

Comment: @4castle The point is moot. The question is tagged Scala and Scala regex doesn't support this.

Comment: @revo It's a regex solution regardless of the number of regexes used. I'm not sure if it's possible though to do the entire operation with just one regex.

Comment: I didn't say it is not a regex solution. @4castle

Comment: @revo I took the challenge. Here's one regex: `\s+(?!(?>[^()]*(\((?:[^()]*(?1)?)+?\)))*$)` [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL7xR7/5). It could probably be optimized. There's probably some bugs too, it just needs more work.

Comment: @revo Much more optimized: `\s+(*SKIP)(?!([^()]*+\((?>[^()]*+(?1)?)+?\))*+[^()]*+$)`

Comment: I don't think [it is right](https://regex101.com/r/bF1fO6/1). @4castle

Comment: @revo I had to make the assumption that all parentheses were balanced. I couldn't write variable-width look-behinds to make that check.

Comment: That's good but it doesn't meet the needs. I'd never go with recursions if they wanna do their half of the job. That's just nasty. @4castle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
def squeezeParens(str: String): String =
  str.foldLeft(("",0)){ case ((result, depth),c) => c match {
    case '('              => (result + c, depth+1)
    case ')' if depth > 0 => (result + c, depth-1)
    case ' ' if depth > 0 => (result,     depth)
    case  _               => (result + c, depth)
  }}._1
```

It should remove all space characters after the first '(' until it finds the matching ')'.  It removes spaces even if the matching ')' is not found.

Answer (score 3):

While @jwvh's answer solves the problem, I'd do it slightly differently:

```
def squeeze(inputString: String, depth: Integer = 0): String = {
  if (inputString.isEmpty) ""
  else
    inputString.head match {
      case '(' => '(' + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth + 1)
      case ')' if depth > 0 => ')' + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth - 1)
      case ' ' if depth > 0 => squeeze(inputString.tail, depth)
      case c : Char => c + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth)
    }
}
```

This leads to a slightly cleaner design, where you use default arguments so you don't have to be passing a tuple down the line. You can also easily generalize this:

```
def squeeze(inputString: String, depth: Integer = 0)
           (remove: Char, replace: String)
           (open: Char, close: Char)
           : String = {
  if (inputString.isEmpty) { "" }
  else {
    inputString.head match {
      case `open` => open + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth + 1)(remove, replace)(open, close)
      case `close` if depth > 0 =>
        close + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth - 1)(remove, replace)(open, close)
      case `remove` if depth > 0 =>
        replace + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth)(remove, replace)(open, close)
      case c : Char => c + squeeze(inputString.tail, depth)(remove, replace)(open, close)
    }
  }
}

val squeezeParen: (String) => (String) = squeeze(_)(' ', "")('(', ')')
val underscoreBracket: (String) => (String) = squeeze(_)(' ', "_")('[', ']')
```

Correctness:

```
val a = "aaa   bbb   ccc   (   1   +   2   )"
val a_correct = "aaa   bbb   ccc   (1+2)"

val b = "(  1  +  2  )  +  (  3  +  4  )"
val b_correct = "(1+2)  +  (3+4)"

val c = "[ a + 5 + (   1   +  2)]"
val c_correct = "[ a + 5 + (1+2)]"
val c_alt = "[_a_+_5_+_(___1___+__2)]"

squeezeParen(a) == a_correct  // true
squeezeParen(b) == b_correct  // true
squeezeParen(c) == c_correct  // true
underscoreBracket(c) == c_alt  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex simply cannot do this. They are only powerful enough to decide strings with a fixed number of nested parentheses. This is an important theorem in Theory of Computation. See part 1 of Brian Sipser "Introduction to Theory of Computation".

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't say anything about nested parentheses, so I'll assume any spaces inside at least 1 level of parentheses should be removed.

This answer doesn't uses regexs, but it does work.

```
def removeSpacesInParens(str: String): String = {
    var parenCount = 0

    str.toList.map{
        case '(' => parenCount+=1; "("
        case ')' => parenCount-=1; ")"
        case c: Char => 
            if(c!=' '){
                c
            }else{
                if(parenCount>=1){""}else{" "}
            }
    }.mkString
}
```

When applied to `[ a + 5 + (   1   +  2)]`

The result is: `[ a + 5 + (1+2)]`

Answer (score -1):

just trim all the white spaces by:

```
s filter (_ != ' ')
```

Comment: that removes all the spaces from the string, i need to remove the spaces only in the parenthesis, other spaces in the string should remain.

Comment: What about the case that the parenthesis are not matched, for example `(3 + 5 ` and `7 + 8)` ?

Comment: then you don't remove anything, as it is not between parenthesis